# Homeomorphic open sets have homeomorphic open balls

Tags: general-topology

If $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $R^n$, how to prove that there are two open balls $B_U$ and $B_V$ in $U$ and $V$ such that these two open balls are homeomorphic?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: They would both be open balls in $\Bbb R^n$. Any two open balls in $\Bbb R^n$ are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

Any two open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic (to the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus to each other too). And any non-empty open set contains an open ball.

$B(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the homeomorphism $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+\|x\|}: \mathbb{R}^n \to B(0,1)$. The rest is scaling and translating.